# Magento-2 installer not moving beyond step 5

Tags: magento2, installer

I have been trying to install magento-2 since over a week now but **each time the magento installer gets stuck at step-5 ( see attached picture of screen)**

**The next button clicks, but is irresponsive.**

The magento version I am installing is version 2.1.5

Any help or advise is very much appreciated.

Thank you.
[image: magento2 installer stuck step5]

Comment: Check the browser console and check what error it gives ?